# Совет по дипломной работе

Tags: моделирование

Всем привет !
Учусь на специальности "Математическое и компьютерное моделирование",
посоветуйте темы для дипломной работы по специальности с уклоном в веб, имеется опыт программирование на Java,PHP с версткой HTML/CSS/JavScript дружу :)

Comment: Диплом всё равно будет по математическому моделированию. Веб - болько обертка. Хотя может по распознаванию образов, нейронным сетям реализация в вебе будет достаточно интересной и кому-то полезной.

Comment: @vinger4 Вот точно, распознование и построение 3D моделей интересно, нейронные сети тоже, спасибо, буду рассматривать варианты )

Comment: Мультиагентные системы - тоже тема набирает обороты. Квантовые процессоры.

Comment: Было бы круто сделать проект, который делал бы фотографии модели с нескольких сторон и компоновал их в 3D модель, которую можно в браузере покрутить.

Comment: Моделирование поведения аудитории сайтов типа facebook, twitter и т.д.?

Comment: @lampa Уже есть такое ) Вот думаю подучить Java в связке с OpenGL реализовать это ) 
@alexlz интересная идея, уже правдо читал что делали это по лайкам )

Comment: @Bimawa можно поподробнее ? Не слышал про такое, что это и с чем едят? Интрижка появилась :)

Comment: @gold Долго объяснять http://bit.ly/1dl74Nh нанониты :)

Comment: @Bimawa окей, гляну)Вроде интересно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас моделирование и вы планируете заниматься `Web` можно эти два дела совместить. На хабре пролетала статья про `WebGL`. Можно начать изучать эту технологию. 
ознакомительные ссылки снизу:

- [WebGL (Web-based Graphics Library)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL)
- [WebGL Урок 3 - немного движения](http://russian-webgl.blogspot.com/)
- [Впечатляющие примеры WebGL](http://habrahabr.ru/post/190388/)

Comment: Игра с медведем прикольная, гляну в сторону WebGL, спасибо!
Буду пробовать в связке с вышеперечисленными темами использовать.

Comment: вторая ссылка, что на blogpost не очень удачная. Во-первых перевод не полный, во-вторых скопипастив код, не получится запустить. Лучше читать оригинал WebGL up and runing - найти легко, правда полного и современного перевода не видел.

+ В оригинальных, уже обновленных статьях, используется другая библиотека для работы с матрицами, наверное не просто так.

Comment: @moron Почитаю литературу на английском, почему бы нет )